# Mapbox single marker change color onclick

Tags: javascript, mapbox

Iam just wondering how to change marker color using onclick function. Im trying to achieve it in this way: but something is wrong...Can anyone help me??

```
var testmarker = L.marker([74.18, -15.56], {
      icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({
        'marker-color': '#9c89cc'
      })
    })
    .bindPopup(testmarker)
    .addTo(map);
testmarker.on('click', function(e) {
L.marker(setColor('red'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `setIcon` method of `L.Marker` in your `click` handler to set a new icon:

> Changes the marker icon.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-seticon

```
testmarker.on('click', function() {
    this.setIcon(
        L.mapbox.marker.icon({
            'marker-color': 'red'
        })
    );
});
```

Comment: thank you very much! This is what i wanted to do:) and additional question...to come back to previous state of color #9c89cc' i should use testmarker.off